# Is there a list of required graphics assets for iOS apps in the app store?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Google provides a [clear list of graphics assets](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870) are needed for promotion in their Play market, as well as [sizes and requirements for launcher icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html).

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find a similar list of graphics assets and icon requirements for iPhone apps in Apple's iTunes store.

Does such a list exist?

Comment: Have you looked in the developer portal?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: First place I looked. Maybe it's in there, but I haven't come across it.

Comment: I'd look in the iTunes Connect section. The list isn't big, though, just a 512 px iTunes icon and screenshots, as far as I know.

Comment: I found a developer guide in the iTunes Connect section. It has scattered hints, and says additional graphics might be required if the iTunes administration requests it. Still, there isn't really a concrete list like the Android one.

Comment: Well, if there isn't a full list dedicated to it, it's probably because it would be a short list :P. I found this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/CreateYourAppRecordiniTunesConnect/CreateYourAppRecordiniTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH6-SW1) which includes what you need to provide. As for the "additional" graphics, they are probably needed ONLY if your app is promoted or featured, so don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the App Store you'll need one 1024px icon and at least one screenshot in retina solution (two if your app is universal - one for iPhone one for iPad)

In your app you'll need at least one icon for each device type you support (iPhone/iPad), but you probably should provide more. For different icon sizes an app should support please refer to [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html).

Comment: That link is referring to UIKit general documentation home page.

Answer (score 6):

The link in the answer of pre doesn't work anymore, so I'll provide the links I've found useful for gathering information about app assets:

1. [First Steps: Identifying Your App in iTunes Connect](http://bit.ly/ios-identify-app)
2. [iTunes Connect App Properties](http://bit.ly/ios-app-properties)

The first link will provide you with some general guidelines on how the artwork and text will be shown in the App Store while the second one is a detailed list of all assets that need to be filled in or provided.